# Printing pdf custom page order

Tags: linux, pdf, printing

I would like to print a pdf file in the following way:
Suppose document.pdf has 30 pages. The page order should be:
1,16;2,17;3,18; ... 15,30 (i.e. two pages per side, one-sided).

Is there any easy solution for that in linux?

Note:

After printing, I want to cut the pages into half, so I get A/5 pages, and I don't want to reorder the sheets manually.

Comment: What program is that generated in? Depending on it you might have certain options or not. [Printing in booklet format on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214538/printing-in-booklet-format).

Comment: It's generated in latex.
I don't want to print booklet format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a command line solution use [pdftk's shuffle](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftk) to get a new pdf with pages arranged in the desired order. Then use [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam) to put 2 pages on one side by side.

```
pdftk input.pdf shuffle 1-15 16-End output temp.pdf

pdfjam temp.pdf --nup 2x1 --letterpaper --landscape --outfile output.pdf
```

**EDIT** just tested my suggestion from comment to turn second half 180° to have
similar borders and it did work a treat with a 4 page sample pdf:

```
pdftk input.pdf cat 1-2 output temp1.pdf
pdftk input.pdf cat 3-4south output temp2.pdf
pdftk A=temp1.pdf B=temp2.pdf shuffle A B output temp.pdf

pdfjam temp.pdf --nup 2x1 --a4paper --landscape --outfile output.pdf
```

Albeit testing under windows and using Acrobat Reader for printing 2in1

[image]

Comment: Using your solution and pdftk's dump_data I was able to write a script where you don't have to specify the middle page manually.

`pdftk my.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages`

Comment: Might be a good idea then to turn the second half 180 degrees so printing margins wouldn't produce different borders

Comment: How to turn the second half 180 degrees?

Comment: See [pdftk cat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftk)

Answer (score 2):

Open the print dialog of Acrobat Reader, give the sequence of pages to print (1,16,2,17,3,18 ... 15,30) and select multiple for two pages per sheet.

Comment: I want to avoid specifying manually the sequence of pages to print.

Comment: You just asked for an easy solution. You probably should spend some more time refining your question. In addition you can easily generate that sequence using a script. The easiest solution to your problem would be to actually print in A5.

Comment: This works in the Acrobat Reader 2020 (though not in Google Chrome print dialogue). Note that selecting multiple pages per sheet is not necessary.